# Publish website via Web Deploy

Tags: asp.net, web, webdeploy

I am publishing a MVC website using web deploy. the Publish succeeds but the website never loads. I think it might be the url I have given it. I am using Windows Server 2012. This is an internal server for testing. But the URL I have used in IIS config and web config is a made up url that is not registered. i.e. logman.com. Am I doing this wrong? Since it will only run on our network, should I use some ip address instead? How should I configure this?

edit * with some new settings i am using an ip adress from the Edit Bindings menu. Not giving it a host name;
here are the results from visual studio:

```
`2>Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://myserver/msdeploy.axd?site=lmsmobile.com ...
2>Adding ACL's for path (lmsmobile.com)
2>Adding ACL's for path (lmsmobile.com)
2>Updating file (lmsmobile.com\bin\LMSMobile.dll).
2>Updating file (lmsmobile.com\bin\LMSMobile.pdb).
2>Updating file (lmsmobile.com\Views\Web.config).
2>Updating file (lmsmobile.com\Web.config).
2>Adding ACL's for path (lmsmobile.com)
2>Adding ACL's for path (lmsmobile.com)
2>Publish Succeeded.
2>Site was published successfully http://10.58.158.75/
 Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped 
 Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped`
```

These are my publish settings:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<publishData>
  <publishProfile
    publishUrl="https://myserver:8172/msdeploy.axd"
    msdeploySite="lmsmobile.com"
    destinationAppUrl="http://10.58.158.75:80/"
    mySQLDBConnectionString=""
    SQLServerDBConnectionString=""
    profileName="Default Settings"
    publishMethod="MSDeploy"
    userName="MYSERVERNAME\myusername" />
</publishData>`
```

Currently when i navigate to the ip adress I get the IIS 8 Web page. Still can't see my site.

Edit 2:

I got past the IIS page by entering the IP address and refreshing the page (shift + refresh). I get a 403 forbidden. I changed the Directory browser settings in IIS to enable and when i refresh I get the directory listing of the folder where my site exists. Still no website. Set directory browsing to disable I get 403.

Comment: If you're deploying to a fake URL that doesn't load what exactly do you mean by "publish succeeding" then?

Comment: Visual Studio says it completed successfully. see my edits above.

Answer (score 0):

internally for testing I would consider using an ip address. To get the dns domain name to resolve correctly it would need to be added to your internal dns server to point at your web server.

Multiple web sites can be run for different phases of development by using the same ip address and when the site is created assign to a 4 digit port number like 192.168.100.201:8090.

This would need to be configured as part of the bindings for the web site when configured for IIS.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not to familiar with ip addresses. How do I know which one to use? Will IIS assign a random one? I know where to change this in IIS. I just don't know how to obtain the ip address. Also, to be clear, If I want to use a friendly url like logman.com. This has to be configured and pointed to my web server. Like a hosting company would do?

Comment: your web server has an ip address correct? normally if this is set up without any other sites (new install) publish to the ip address of the server (which defaults to port 80)

Comment: what settings are you using with web deploy where it looks like the publish is working? post a screen shot of your publish settings please.

Comment: please see my edited post above for my publish settings.

Comment: "destinationAppUrl="http://10.58.158.75:80/" this indicates that the web site is published to port 80, the format of the .pubxml file for visual studio 2013 is different from what you have published. Suggest that you connect to your IIS server and see if the bits are in the default site folder (looking at the properties of the IIS server will help find the correct directory). There may be a binding (under basic bindings for the default site :80 that needs to be removed for lmsmobile.com and use default web site unless you plan to create a new web instance (which needs to exist before publish.

Comment: my bits are in wwwroot/LMS Mobile folder. I publish with the config of my IP then Visual Studio lops off the port 80 bit. Even when I navigate to my IP/port 80 it resolves to just the IP address. It is now showing the directory for the website.

Comment: I am not using Default web site . My site exists in a new instance. Default website is configured for port 80.

Comment: I've tried port 8090. Nothing seems to work. I can only see the directory of my files.

Comment: Solved. I din't have asp.net 4.5 installed on the server.